# is there a way to get the execution order of JavaScript for Debug purposes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having alot of issues with Asynchronous functions and I was wondering if there are any tools which would show me the execution order of my script after it has run (without stopping it). I have Firebug but I do not see an option to do this.

The Reason I am looking for this is I have a callback being called in a `.done()` for my `.get()` but It for some reason fails sometimes so I am trying to track down where exactly this is happening.

This is not me asking how to solve the Asynchronous issue (although suggestions are welcome) but more I would like to learn how to track it down myself. Any advice or links to tools/tutorial a greatly Welcome

Comment: `console.log('myFunctionName')` in your functions.

Comment: Agree with @Cerbrus. Just place a `console.log()` to each function call or point of interest in your code.

Comment: I just can't stress enough how important it is to log every step in your code if you're trying to debug it. It'll help you determine where your code breaks, with ease.

Comment: Also breakpoints: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints. Works similarly in Firebug and other tools.

Comment: As Cerbrus said, logging is extremely important, but something even more important is remembering to check you `var`d all of your variables. All too often people forget and there is a variable name conflict, the effects of which are made worse when using _asynchronous_ functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log('myFunctionName')` in your functions. You can also log variables, to double-check if their content is right.

Basically, something like this:

```
var myInt = 0;

function init(){
    console.log('init()')
    stepOne();
    myInt = 10
    console.log('Between steps')
    stepTwo();
    // more stuff;
    console.log('init() end');
}

function stepOne(){
    console.log('stepOne()', myInt);
    // Do stuff
    console.log('stepOne() end', myInt);
}

function stepTwo(){
    console.log('stepTwo()', myInt);
    // Do stuff
    console.log('stepTwo() end', myInt);
}
```

Etc...

If you'll see something like this in your logs, after running `init()`:

```
init()
stepOne() 0
stepOne() end 0
Between steps
stepTwo() 10
```

Then that means your code is breaking in `stepTwo()`.